# How to add a listener for all scroll events?

Tags: scroll, addeventlistener, reason, bucklescript, bs-webapi

I need to add a listener for all scroll events in Reason React or all scroll affects affecting the main window (either would work).

Trying this but the event does not trigger:

```ml
open Webapi.Dom;

Document.addEventListener("scroll", onScroll);
```

P.S. Also, there's a mention that `addEventListener` is a partial application, so I'm worried that this is potentially a 3-argument function expecting a target object rather than a window-wide function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your suspicion that this is a three-argument function is correct. It expects a reference to the document it should attach the event listener to. The document that is currently in scope is conveniently accessible through `Webapi.Dom.document`, so you should only need to add that:

```
Document.addEventListener("scroll", onScroll, document);
```

This convention is used everywhere in bs-webapi. Functions are not hard-coded to the document or window currently in scope because they aren't the only one you *can* use, even if they usually are the ones you *want* to use.